# How many Flip Flops will this code produce?

Tags: vhdl, flip-flop

so I have an exam coming up and I am solving tutes. One of the questions is very basic but I don't think I have the exact logic down for it. It simply gives me a small bit of the code and asks how many Flip Flops will this produce. Could you help me understand how I can find this out? Thanks!

```
Architecture rtl of ex is
    signal a,b,q, int: bit_vector(3 downto 0);
begin
    process(clk)
    begin
        If  clk = '1' and clk'event then 
            int <= int +1;     
            q <=int;
            a <= b xor q;
        end if;
    end process; 
    b <= int
end;
```

Comment: how far have you got? Explain what you think the answer is and why, and you may get a good critique on that answer.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Well I understand that since there's an 'IF' statement within the process, it needs to cover all possible cases or there will be latches. Now the  if statement only involves the clk signal and none of the 'a, b, q and int' so I think there should be 4 latches in total? That's my thinking anyway. I also suspect that since there are 3 signal assignment statements the 4 latches will be repeated 2 more times so 12 in total. But I am not sure.

Comment: @bzrk89, You're a bit confused.  Here's a rule: Latches will NEVER be generated in a sequential process (a process that uses a clock for rising edge detection).  Your rule stated above about covering all possible cases of an IF statement is true for combinational processes (ones that do not use a clock).  Here's more information about [How to avoid latches in your FPGA design](http://www.nandland.com/articles/how-to-avoid-transparent-latches-in-vhdl-and-verlog.html)

Comment: @Russell So there won't be any latches in this piece of code? I was also taught that all processes are sequential but they contain concurrent statements so can you please explain how many latches will this produce and why?

Comment: @bzrk89, correct.  Zero latches.  There will however be flip-flops.  Do you understand the difference between the two?  Not all processes are sequential.  Either your professor is confused or you misunderstood what he/she said.

Comment: @Russell Got it. I don't know why I was confusing latches with Flip Flops. I do believe that I will get FFs in this process and not latches, for the reason that you mentioned. Yes FFs are made of latches.

Comment: All process code is read sequentially, but calling it a "sequential process" may have other implications. It is also not necessarily correct to say that "processes contain concurrent statements". Processes technically contain sequential statements, some of which may have the same form as concurrent statements.

Comment: Break it down. For each assignment, what do you expect to see - how many FFs, and why? (There is also a snarky answer, based on the fact that all the assignments are to internal signals, therefore none to output ports, but I don't think that's what the question calls for)

Comment: @BrianDrummond 4 FFs for each assignment? Since none of the signals were in the sensitivity list?

Comment: @BrianDrummond OK so I have so far understood properly why there are FFs produced here and not latches (the rising edge of the clk is what the conditional is looking for). And I think, it's because there's not else statement.But I only see 3 assignments so I do not understand why the answer is 12?

Comment: Good. That's progress. Now look more closely at the signal declarations...

Comment: @BrianDrummond Alright so there are a total of 4 signals declared. One of them is a bit_vector of 4 bits. If there was a single assignment statement then I would see 4 FFs since the clk is what the conditional is looking for and not the signals? Is that correct? And since there are 3 assignment statements, I see 4 FFs repeated for each assignment statement, totaling 12?

Comment: That's correct, and should be good enough for a C. For an A, I would expect:  since Q and B are both copies of Int, and A is an XOR of two related signals, can any of them be optimised away? If not, why not? You'd need to reason in clock cycles and delta cycles about each signal.

Answer (score 2):

OK, here's the correct - but snarky - answer, with the caveat that it is almost certainly not what the question calls for.

Given the above Architecture declaration, it is clear that there are no assignments to anything other than internal signals. We are not shown the Entity declaration, but from the Architecture we can assume at least an `Input` port named `clk`. There may or may not be outputs; we cannot tell, however they are irrelevant as there are no assignments to them.

Therefore the above architecture cannot affect any outputs, so it will be entirely trimmed during the Logic Minimisation phase of synthesis, and generate no Flipflops whatsoever.

Comment: This is true, and would certainly be marked wrong on any test.  I do like it though.